# Risky sign-ins report via Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Via UI I am referring to the [Risky sign-ins report in the Azure Active Directory portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-security-risky-sign-ins).

Can't seem to find how to retrieve "risky sign-ins" report programmatically. Well, I can find the ["old way"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference) from AAD Graph API (not Microsoft Graph).

Is this included in Microsoft Graph already (and I didn't find it)? Or even someplace else?

Activity Feed on Office 365 Management API seems to have the raw data via [Audit.AzureActiveDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#working-with-the-office-365-management-activity-api)) which is kind of funny that is yet again somewhere I didn't expect to find that sort of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the REST call you're looking for is `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents`. The response includes a list of [Identity risk event objects](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/identityriskevent) that look like the following example:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.unfamiliarLocationRiskEvent",
  "closedDateTime": "2016-01-29T20:03:57.7872426Z",
  "createdDateTime": "2016-01-29T00:01:49.126468Z",
  "id": "ec50e9fb-9da1-215b-e18c-b7e2a716b2a6-9eaaa2e3-4681-ae31-1eb6-7e46ae11ac89-db69711e-9324-ec99-f010-6e63fb972e98",
  "ipAddress": "176.10.104.240",
  "location": "Bern, CH",
  "riskEventDateTime": "2016-01-29T00:00:56.2255665Z",
  "riskEventStatus": "remediated",
  "riskLevel": "medium",
  "riskType": "UnfamiliarLocationRiskEvent",
  "userDisplayName": "Jon Doe",
  "userId": "9eaaa2e3-4681-ae31-1eb6-7e46ae11ac89",
  "userPrincipalName": "jon@contoso.com"
}
```

Relevant documentation

- [Get started with Azure Active Directory Identity Protection and Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-identityprotection-graph-getting-started)
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/identityriskevent_list

Comment: Thanks. I kind of was expecting it in Reports. Obviously it is a list... my bad.